# RDP6.0 Bulk Decompression

Tags: rdp, compression

Maybe any one have aditional information about implementation RDP6.0 Bulk decompression. I use MS specification and this blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2010/06/10/rdp-6-0-bulk-decompression-walkthrough.aspx, but still have some problems....

Answer (score 1):

The answer for my question is here:

http://vs-page.blogspot.com/2011/04/implementing-rdp-60-bulk-decompression.html